# Open multiple instances of Adobe Acrobat Professional

Tags: adobe-acrobat

When I run OCR on a PDF file using Acrobat, I am not able to use Acrobat at the same time to view or work with other PDF files. Is there anyway to get around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was easily able to run multiple instances Acrobat Pro XI (11.0) by simply typing  "run" from the start menu, and in the "run window" typing

then in "run" entering:

```
 "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat 11.0\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe" /n
```

and repeat. I could scan and OCR in one, and do operations in the other.

awesome

Comment: Great, works! Just to note for newbs (like myself) that it may depend on where your Acrobat.exe folder is. In my case the correct command was `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe" /n`

Comment: Note that according to the other answer by ConanOfRottingham, the full filespec of Acrobat is not needed. The code above can be replaced with simply `Acrobat /n`, no matter where the program files are located. Verified in Acrobat XI Pro.

Answer (score 4):

In Windows 10 x64bit Professional running Adobe Acrobat DC.

1. In the Windows Search box type "Run" without the quotes.
2. Click on the "Run" app.
3. Type `acrobat /n` in the blank field provided and then click on the "OK" button.

That's it! You now have another instance of Acrobat running. This is helpful when sending say 4 very large files to 4 different printers all at the same time. You can have each instance of acrobat sending 4 different large documents to 4 different printers simultaneously.

Comment: Verified that this also works in Acrobat XI Pro.

Comment: The new instance can be opened with a specific pdf file by adding the filespec: `Acrobat /n "C:\path\FileToOpen.pdf"`.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, if you have enabled the option to open documents as new tabs in the same window, and provided you have several such open tabs, is to drag one of the tabs out of the Acrobat window using your mouse. A new instance of Acrobat will then be created, containg that tab.

Answer (score -1):

The short answer: no.

A bit a longer answer: Acrobat is not set up to run in multiple instances. What you can do, and this is now also sanctioned and supported by Adobe, is running Reader with the same major version number (Acrobat XI and Reader XI, or Acrobat X and Reader X).

If you happen to be on Mac, it is not sanctioned officially by Adobe, but if you know what you are doing, you can run different versions of Acrobat concurrently; I have a development where for changing the document, JavaScript has to be off, but for testing it has to be on. So, I run Acrobat 7 with JavaScript deactivated and Acrobat 9 or XI with active JavaScript, and for displaying important documentation, I have Reader XI active as well.

For Windows, I am not quite sure whether Acrobat and Reader can run concurrently; they can be installed on the same machine.

Comment: Note that the Windows part of this answer is wrong. See the other answers.