# How can I run multiple instances of Adobe Acrobat on different Virtual Desktops on Windows 10, on One Monitor?

Tags: windows-10, pdf, adobe-acrobat, multiple-instances

https://superuser.com/a/1443271/1770221 - This answer accurately represents my situation; running Adobe Acrobat on Win 10 on an x64 computer.

Just for context, this is what happens in my scenario:
VD1 has Adobe acrobat opened with a PDF file. I go to VD4 and now I want to open another PDF file that is a different topic. BUT, when I open the app OR the file, it just takes me BACK to VD1!

Regarding the link above containing the solution to my problem:

What I am afraid of is that, I'm not familiar with programming, so I'm wary of following these instructions as; what if something goes wrong OR if I encounter any bugs or glitches after following these commands? Therefore; is there a way on reversing this action, so that everything is back to normal (w/o factoring resetting ofc).

Another question to ask: is this solution also applicable to use for another PDF reader that doesn't support multiple instances? Why type `acrobat` and not the full name `adobe acrobat` when running the command?

Comment: Natively Adobe opens multiple files in one window (recent versions, Reader and Acrobat). I don't think you can do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Sandboxie Plus
2. Open Sandboxie Plus
3. Right Click DefaultBox
4. Run
5. Run Program
6. Add Acrobat Path
7. Create New Virtual Desktop
8. Tab + WinKey
9. Drag Second Acrobat Window To New Virtual Desktop

For Multiple Instances Create New Boxes and repeat process