# Acrobat 7 multiple windows -move pages between them?

Tags: adobe-acrobat

In this thread, opening Acrobat 7 in multiple windows was discussed and the solution was to call it with acrobat /n (from whether it is installed):
[Open multiple instances of Adobe Acrobat Professional](https://superuser.com/questions/803095/open-multiple-instances-of-adobe-acrobat-professional#new-answer?newreg=27a9e566dff34b93a7460e61ea3c1dbd).
I can confirm that worked (in Windows 7, but I'm looking for a solution to a Win10 box I've just set up), but I couldn't use it to do what I really want to do, which is to move pages from one pdf document to another, with each document in its own window, possibly on separate monitors.  I can move pages between documents if the documents are open in the same instance of Acrobat 7, but they all share one screen, which can make it hard to see everything necessary to conveniently perform the task. So, I was hoping that the multiple instances solution would support that use-case.
Alas, it doesn't. Is there any way to make this work, or do I need to buy a later version of Acrobat or some other PDF manager (I have one in mind, if necessary).

Comment: The same solution should work on Windows 10.  It shouldn't matter if the question was about Acrobat on Windows 7. Newer versions of Acrobat let you view multiple PDFS in a single window or break each tab into it's own window.  Acrobat 7 does not.

Comment: Please rephrase your question, a "wall of text" is not very reader-friendly. A question with good readability will result in more attention and better answers.

Comment: I gave up trying to prettify my  question, since neither adding two spaces (supposedly introduces a line break, but doesn't), nor adding a return (just closes out the post) worked to break up the text. But given that you've confirmed that Acrobat 7 just won't do what I need (tested using Windows 7 where I'd had it installed for years), there's no point in installing it in Windows 10.